# Update website after changing attribute value using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently using bs4 to scrape the following [website](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/community?p=AAPL). I want to change the view from 'Top Reactions' to 'Latest Reactions' but the only way to do this is by adding "selected" as one of the classes of the tag around 'Latest Reactions'. After doing this though, the html code doesn't change and 'Top Reactions' is still displayed. Is there a way to fix this using bs4?

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/community?p={0}".format(ticker)
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

latest_button = soup.find('li', {'class' : 'H(44px)'})
latest_button['class'] = latest_button['class'] + 'selected'

comments = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "comment"})


for comment in comments: # Goes through the latest n messages
    post = {
        
    }
    
    post["content"] = comment.find("div", {"class": "C($c-fuji-grey-l)"}).text

    print(post)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautifulsoup can't update the sites content you should use `selenium`

Comment: @AminGuermazi is there a way to run selenium without a browser, so that is can run in the cloud?

Comment: I don't think selenium works without a browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for Selenium. You can get the data by api. Simply changing a parameter in the url from sort by `popular` to `createdAt` will do that for you.

```
import requests
import time
import re
import statistics


ticker = 'TSLA'

# Get prid
url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/community?p={ticker}'.format(ticker=ticker)
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
prid_search = re.search('{\"prid\":\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)', response)
prid = prid_search.group(1)

finmb_search = re.findall('finmb_([\d]*)', response)
finmb = statistics.mode(finmb_search)

api_url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/_finance_doubledown/api/resource/canvass.getMessageList;apiVersion=v1;context=finmb_{finmb};count=20;index=null;lang=en-GB;namespace=yahoo_finance;oauthConsumerKey=finance.oauth.client.canvass.prod.consumerKey;oauthConsumerSecret=finance.oauth.client.canvass.prod.consumerSecret;query=namespace%20%3D%20%22yahoo_finance%22%20and%20(contextId%3D%22finmb_{finmb}%22%20or%20tag%3D%22{ticker}%22);rankingProfile=canvassPCRDProfile;region=GB;sortBy=createdAt;spaceId=1186050005;type=null;userActivity=true?bkt=finance-GB-en-GB-def&device=desktop&ecma=modern&feature=canvassOffnet%2CccOnMute%2CdisableCommentsMessage%2Cdebouncesearch100%2CdeferDarla%2CecmaModern%2CemptyServiceWorker%2Cenable3pConsent%2CenableCCPAFooter%2CenableCMP%2CenableConsentData%2CenableGuceJs%2CenableGuceJsOverlay%2CenableNavFeatureCue%2CenablePrivacyUpdate%2CenableStreamDebounce%2CenableTheming%2CenableUpgradeLeafPage%2CenableVideoDocking%2CenableVideoURL%2CenableXrayNcp%2CenableXrayNcpInModal%2CenableXrayTickerEntities%2CenableYahooSans%2CenableYodleeErrorMsgCriOS%2CncpListStream%2CncpPortfolioStream%2CncpQspStream%2CncpStream%2CncpStreamIntl%2CncpTopicStream%2CnewContentAttribution%2CnewLogo%2CoathPlayer%2CrelatedVideoFeature%2CuseNextGenHistory%2CvideoNativePlaylist%2CsunsetMotif2%2CenableUserPrefAPI%2CenableSingleRail%2CenhanceAddToWL%2Carticle2_csn%2CenableStageAds%2CsponsoredAds&intl=uk&lang=en-GB&partner=none&prid={prid}&region=GB&site=finance&tz=Europe%2FLondon&ver=0.102.4664&returnMeta=true'.format(ticker=ticker,finmb=finmb,prid=prid)
jsonData = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

messages = jsonData['data']['canvassMessages']
for message in messages:
    author = message['meta']['author']['nickname']
    createdAt = message['meta']['createdAt']
    createdAt = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p', time.localtime(createdAt))
    text = message['details']['userText']
    print('%s posted at: %s \n%s\n\n' %(author, createdAt, text))
```

**Output:**

```
trippett posted at: 2021-04-19 02:51:05 PM 
I sat on the fence for 3 weeks about joining (http://Stocks-tracker.com) for their weekly picks. Big mistake. AAPL exploded and I completely missed out. Don’t make the same mistake I made. Join them today.


Maqrsqrt posted at: 2021-04-19 02:51:05 PM 
Gonna makes me lotsa money


festus posted at: 2021-04-19 02:50:27 PM 
165 into earnings


Maqrsqrt posted at: 2021-04-19 02:49:58 PM 
Flush those daytraders!!


matthew posted at: 2021-04-19 02:48:54 PM 
Bought 1 apple share! Woo


steve posted at: 2021-04-19 02:48:36 PM 
go baby, go  enjoy the ride to 150+ this week 


Aleem posted at: 2021-04-19 02:48:03 PM 
If only this hits 145 this week 


felix posted at: 2021-04-19 02:47:55 PM 
I think by July it should be in the $200


Akshay posted at: 2021-04-19 02:47:41 PM 
What's the news?


Maqrsqrt posted at: 2021-04-19 02:46:32 PM 
look out below!!


michael posted at: 2021-04-19 02:45:17 PM 
Where’s Giuseppe ? Lol


Kafil posted at: 2021-04-19 02:43:38 PM 
Lets stay above $ 135 for today


Tina posted at: 2021-04-19 02:42:58 PM 
yesss! $135 crossed!


Kafil posted at: 2021-04-19 02:42:57 PM 
BINGO


Jack posted at: 2021-04-19 02:37:59 PM 
And the climb into earnings continues


Trader posted at: 2021-04-19 02:37:43 PM 
Wants to run to 141??


ray posted at: 2021-04-19 02:36:35 PM 
Turning green


Tina posted at: 2021-04-19 02:36:34 PM 
Way to go! This will be $138 tomorrow at 3.30 pm


Kafil posted at: 2021-04-19 02:36:16 PM 
Watch out if we brake $ 135 next stop will be $ 140


Richie Rich posted at: 2021-04-19 02:34:57 PM 
134.98 then down
```

Comment: This is great, just wondering how you change the stock ticker, tried to change 'AAPL' in the URL but didn't seem to work

Comment: Also is there any documentation you could reference me to?

Comment: what ticker were you trying to change AAPL to?

Comment: Id want to change it to any but TSLA for example

Comment: Ya doesnt look to be as easy as just changing the ticker name. Looks like a few other ids go with it. I updated the code above. Give that a try.

Comment: @chitown88 Seems it does not work anymore, I don't really get how it works. Could you help to add some explanations so that I can make it works?

Comment: Also what is prid and finmb? Thanks so much!

Comment: try it again. those are some parameters needed to input into the url

Comment: Thanks @chitown88, currently it seems the website allows to download 30 comments each request, do you think it's possible to get more comment for one requests?